# How to check Raw Files in my iCloud Drive?

Tags: macos, icloud, filesystem

I would like to see all my raw files in my iCloud Drive.

I tried going to https://www.icloud.com/#iclouddrive and `~/Library/Mobile Documents`, but there’re only the “official, ordered and clean” iCloud Drive folder.

From the iCloud preference panel, I can see every app that stores something in my iCloud Drive, but I can’t see what they store.

Is there a complete way to check my iCloud Drive?

EDIT: This is what I mean by “Raw Files”:

[image: iCloud Drive]

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know of to achieve this is by creating a symbolic link to your *iCloud Drive* folder. Open a **Terminal** window and enter the following:

`ln -s ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents ~/Desktop/iCloud\ Drive`

This will place a symbolic link to your *iCloud Drive* on your desktop. You may move it wherever you please.

Starting with **El Capitan**, trying to navigate to that folder using the  <kbd>Cmd  ⌘</kbd><kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> shortcut takes you instead to *~/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs*. Incidentally, that is the same location that the **Favorites** shortcut points to.

Do note that opening most of these folders will take you to *~/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs*. However, you can expand them to inspect their contents in **List View**.

This comes in handy when troubleshooting certain iCloud synchronization issues, such as (in my case), **Text Replacements** not making it to my Mac.